# Django phone number field with country

Tags: python, django, phone-number

How to create a phone number field in `django` form that would take just the phone number without international code.

User should be able to choose a country first and then django should validate the number based on user's country. Validation should be country specific.

Eg: User would choose **'US'** then django should look for numbers that are 10 digit and don't start with 0, else generate error.

Django's phone number-field package has a mandatory requirement for international code. So if a user doesn't know her country phone code ( which is very normal) user wont be able to enter a valid phone number.

Django's `PhoneField` package displays an extension field on the web-page which is unnecessary and I could not find any documentation showing examples using this package.

Thanks

Comment: Just make two fields - one a select input (dropdown) for choosing country code and another text input for phone number.

Comment: Did you tried these ? `PhoneNumberPrefixWidget`, a form widget for selecting a region code and entering a national number and 
`PhoneNumberInternationalFallbackWidget`, a form widget that uses national numbers unless an international number is entered.